# Next Word Prediction using corpus text file in c/c++/objective c

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, macos, n-gram

I am trying to make an next word prediction program using corpus text file.
As we get in Android/iPhone (Quick type in iOS 8). when user type a word and then the next word suggestion is shown to the user and so on...
I have found that we have to make a use of n-gram algorithm 
https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/CS4740/2012sp/lectures/smoothing+backoff-1-4pp.pdf

but there is no code or example available to start with it.
Can any one help me how to start for implementing this algo in c/c++/objective c

Comment: In all those languages?

Comment: `C` and `C++` are different languages, the only similarity is the `C` part :P